# Spark Full Rdd joinWithCassandraTable java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: instead of

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

- I am currently trying to join a spark dataframe to a cassandra table.
- We unfortunately cannot upgrade immediately to the new Datastax connector 2.5.0 and use Direct Joins
- So i am trying the Rdd approach using the existing **joinWithCassandraTable**

Here's My Sample code

```
# Cassandra Table Definition 

custId: text PRIMARY KEY
custName: text
custAddress: text

val testDF = Seq(("event-01", "cust-01"), ("event-02", "cust-02")).toDF(("eventId", "custId"))

val resultRdd = testDF
    .rdd
    .leftJoinWithCassandraTable(
      keyspaceName = "my_key_space",
      tableName = "cust_table",
      selectedColumns = AllColumns,
      joinColumns = SomeColumns("custId")
    )
    .map { case (sparkRow, cassandraRow) =>
      val resultStruct = cassandraRow
        .map(r => Row.fromSeq(r.columnValues))
        .orNull
      Row.fromSeq(sparkRow.toSeq :+ resultStruct)
    }
```

- This throws a **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid row size: 2 instead of 1**
- If i restrict the `testDF` to just have the **custId** column, then this works fine.
- Am i making a mistake somewhere. How can i perform the join on the Full Rdd instead of a projection with just the key column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.on(SomeColumns("custId"))` right after leftJoinWithCassandraTable...

I have [the blog post on the efficient join with Cadsandra](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html), and it describes RDD API as well...

Comment: Thanks for the info. This works for me as well. This is the best approach until we upgrade to use Direct Joins with DataFrames